# How do I evaluate an expression with trignometric functions & also complex numbers in Sagemath?

Tags: math, sage

I wanted to verify if n-th roots of unity are actually the n-th roots of unity?

i.e. if (root)^n = 1

I was trying to use sagemath to do this.

For e.g. for regular expressions sage seems to evaluate stuff

For e.g.

```
sage: x = var('x')
sage: f(x) = (x+2)^3
sage: f(5)
343
```

But I am unable to do this

```
sage: a = var('a')
sage: b = var('b')
sage: f(a, b) = (a + i*b)^3
sage: f(cos((2*pi)/3) , sin((2*pi)/3))
(1/2*I*sqrt(3) - 1/2)^3
```

How do I make sage raise it to power 3 & evaluate?

Comment: @Stef - full_simplify() worked - if you make this as an answer, I will accept it! Thank you

Comment: Note: no need to define `x` before `f(x) = ...` since that line defines both `x` and `f`. Similarly, no need to define `a` and `b` before `f(a, b) = ...` since that line defines all of `a`, `b` and `f `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sage expression has several methods to manipulate it, including expanding, factoring and simplifying:

```
e = f(cos((2*pi)/3) , sin((2*pi)/3))
e.expand()
e.simplify()
e.full_simplify()
e.factor()
```

You can see the list of all available methods by typing the name of the variable, followed by a dot, followed by a tabulation: `e.<tab>`.

In your case, it would appear `e.full_simplify()` should do the trick.

Relevant documentation:

- [sage doc: Symbolic Expressions](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/expression.html);
- [sage doc: Tutorial for Symbolics and Plotting](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/prep/Symbolics-and-Basic-Plotting.html)